Ssl handshake connecting to mongoldb atlas occurs on my Mac, but not on another computer on the same network
{"error": "ac-ietpzrc-shard-00-01.nctb2m7.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),ac-ietpzrc-shard-00-02.nctb2m7.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),ac-ietpzrc-shard-00-00.nctb2m7.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6658e8ba68f277049a92516d, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-ietpzrc-shard-00-00.nctb2m7.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-ietpzrc-shard-00-00.nctb2m7.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-ietpzrc-shard-00-01.nctb2m7.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-ietpzrc-shard-00-01.nctb2m7.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-ietpzrc-shard-00-02.nctb2m7.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-ietpzrc-shard-00-02.nctb2m7.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>"}

I am using Python Flask to set up a local backend server to connect to MongoDB Atlas. On my Mac I get the above error when I make a post request, but on my partner's Windows computer, the post request is successful and updates the DB with no SSL error.
-We are on the same network.
-In the MongoDB cloud console, it's set to take requests from any IP address.
-We are testing the same request in PostMan with the same body header etc.
The following is the code responsible for making the request.
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

app = Flask(__name__)

mongo_uri = "<connection string omitted but the same on both computers>"
client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
db = client.get_database("EduTracker")  # replace 'testcluster' with your database name

@app.route('/students', methods=\['POST'\])
def create_student():
if request.content_type != 'application/json':
return jsonify({"error": "Content-Type must be application/json"}), 415

    data = request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)  # force=True to handle empty body
    if data is None:
        return jsonify({"error": "No input data provided"}), 400
    
    name = data.get('name')
    parent_contact = data.get('parent_contact')
    
    new_student = {
        'name': name,
        'parent_contact': parent_contact
    }
    
    try:
        result = db.students.insert_one(new_student)
        student_id = str(result.inserted_id)
        return jsonify({"message": "Student created successfully", "student_id": student_id}), 201
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(port=8000, debug=True)

We have tried connecting to different WiFi networks, using mobile data, changing ports, and allowing the database to take connections from any IP.

Looks like the CA certificate is not available on this computer. See Which certificate authority signs MongoDB Atlas TLS certificates?. The page provides the link to download the CA at Hard-coded Certificate Authority
